# Is it possible to login user with URL parameter? (DJANGO)

Tags: django, autologin

I want to autologin the user by click with an URL with the format like:

username:password@mysite.com
or
mysite.com/?username=""&password=""

something like this. It would also work with an authentication token:

mysite.com/AUTHTOKEN

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is advisable to encode tokens and definitely not passwords in the URL. If people use this on a publicly acessible computer, then this data appears in the browsers history, and hence it "leaks" credentials.

Comment: In my case, that's no problem. I thought it wouldn't be difficult to implement it. I need this links to autologin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the "Magic-Links" from [django-sesame](https://github.com/aaugustin/django-sesame) to provide auth tokens.

With this token, my users are aible to login via a link like: https://example.com/?sesame=zxST9d0XT9xgfYLvoa9e2myN.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can do something like www.mysite.com/?usename=<>&password=<> and access them in the view as arguments then authenticate the user and login him.
But you must be have a good reason to do it .